# pixi.js particles blocking mouse events for interactive sprites

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite, pixi.js

The PIXI.sprite, which is underneath a `PIXI.particles.Emitter`, has some bound mouse events - `mouseover` and `click`, but they are being blocked by the particles. When mousing over the sprite or clicking on it, the event is not fired.

I found someone having the **[same issue](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1725)**, and his solution was to set the containing `PIXI.container`'s interactive property to `false`.

However, in my situation, I require that the container be interactive for dragging and zooming the map.

How can I allow the sprite's mouse events to be fired, regardless of whether a particles emitter (or even another non-interactive sprite) is overlaid on top of it in respect to the z-axis - while still keeping the container's `interactive = true`?

Comment: I suggest to look at: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/15-pixijs/ , since stackoverflow isn't very active regarding PIXI. I handle events manually (addEventListener on canvas), so unfortunately I don't know much about the PIXIs own event handler.

Comment: I think you can set individual PIXI graphics to be `interactive = true` or not. Have you tried setting the emitted particles to be `interactive = false`?